# How to use variables defined with assign in list elements in freemarker

Tags: list, hashmap, freemarker

i have a freemarker problem. I have one hash map called nodes and i iterate trough it like this:

```
<#list hashmap.collection as nodes>
 .....some displaying
 <#assign nodeName>
${nodes.name}
 </#assign>
   <#list hashmap2.nodeName.collection as nodes2>
    .......some more displaying
```

And this code is not because freemarker is trying to find nodeName key inside the hashmap2... 
Is there a way to do this in freemarker?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `hasmap2[nodeName].collection`. What you put after `.` is always seen as *literally* the sub-variable name, while inside `[]` you can give an arbitrary expression as far as it evaluates to a string. Thus, you may don't need that `#assign` at all, and you could write `hashmap2[nodes.name].collection`.

Also, instead of `<#assign nodeName>${nodes.name}</#assign>` you should just write `<#assign nodeName = nodes.name>`. Again, if you need the assignment at all.

Also since `nodes` store a single node, your code would be more readable if you call it `node`.